# Vimrc autosourcing not working

Tags: vim, vimrc

My vim configuration lives in `$HOME/.vim/vimrc`, which is symlinked to `~/.vimrc`.

Inside my vimrc I have:

```
if has("autocmd")
  autocmd bufwritepost vimrc source $HOME/.vim/vimrc
endif
```

But is not working. I also tried sourcing `$MYVIMRC`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you explain by "it's not working" what isn't working. I'm a little confused as to what you're expecting this to do.

Comment: It should source vimrc after I save it, loading the configuration without having to restart vim. The problem is that is not sourcing the file. Tried several paths with :so [vimrc-path]

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
augroup myvimrc
    au!
    au BufWritePost .vimrc,_vimrc,vimrc,.gvimrc,_gvimrc,gvimrc so $MYVIMRC | if has('gui_running') | so $MYGVIMRC | endif
augroup END
```

Found this solution on SuperUser in Q&A titled: [How do you reload your .vimrc file without restarting vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/132029/how-do-you-reload-your-vimrc-file-without-restarting-vim).

See help on `autocmd-patterns` for more info:

```
:help autocmd-patterns
```

Comment: It's not working either.

Comment: @jviotti - how about this instead? I've updated my answer with another technique I found on SU.

Comment: It didn't work either. I think the problem is on the vimrc path. Manually doing :so $MYVIMRC should work. Tried includign the path: :so $HOME/.vimrc, :so $HOME/.vim/vimrc, :so $MYVIMRC , etc. Nothing seems to find my configuration file

Comment: @jviotti - ughh. I'll keep looking.